# "Edit feature properties directly from the map" by a user who has been sent a link, can then edit a pop-up directly on the map

Tags: carto, editing, popup

Edit feature properties directly from the map:
https://carto.com/blog/edit-feature-properties-directly-from-the-map/

> With the new feature editing modal window you are able to edit the
> properties of your data directly on the map. You only need to click on
> the feature you want to edit and then click the editing icon on the
> left-hand side.

I see this is possible in the Builder stage, but is there any feature/widjet/way to do this *by a user who has been sent the link* and by clicking on the actual point/line/polygon the pop-up comes up and a field in the pop-up can then be edited.

This is a feature in ArcGIS Online.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that action is not allowed in CARTO Builder. The map maker is the only user allowed to do so when it click on the layer, but it is only possible in edit mode, not when it is shared/embeded.